# How safe is setting consumer_timeout to long values like 10years

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

Im guessing it's there for a reason, but I can't seem to find any answer to this question.

In short I have a django app where users get set badges that months or even years down the line need to be auto removed for which I use celery.

My question is will setting consumer_timeout to large values pose a risk for those actions to not be performed or performed early/late (mind you a delay of even a few hours shouldn't be a big deal for long duration tasks)

Comment: I don't see what the connection is between Rabbit's `consumer_timeout` value and your auto-removal of badges after months/years (what are these "badges"?). Maybe you can clarify what the connection is, from your point of view?

Comment: [This `consumer_timeout` setting](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout) is "_a protection mechanism that helps detect buggy (stuck) consumers that never acknowledge deliveries. Such consumers can affect node's on disk data compaction and potentially drive nodes out of disk space._" A "_high value_" is considered to be "_a few hours_". Setting it to 10 years is effectively no different from not having any setting at all.

Comment: Hello thanks for the replies, so It seems I have misunderstood what consumer_timeout is, I thought it was the duration of which tasks are kept before they are thrown out, so my bad for the stupid question. I will turn consumer_timeout as it does not seem necessary for my needs (since if a task gets run then there is no way of it failing and that there would be no way of me akg my tasks outside of the tasks). Thank you a lot for the answers ^^. If anyone is interested the project is this one https://github.com/IanisDonica/genForum

Comment: No problem. I will add an answer, for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`consumer_timeout`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout) setting does not appear to be relevant to your long-term Celery tasks.

The setting serves an unrelated purpose. It is:

> "a protection mechanism that helps detect buggy (stuck) consumers that never acknowledge deliveries. Such consumers can affect node's on disk data compaction and potentially drive nodes out of disk space."

A "high value" is considered to be "a few hours". Setting it to 10 years is effectively no different from not having any setting at all.